# Yii2: $model->validate() is not working

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I wanna create my own login method, but firstly I may try to work with validation and then redirect to the page; however, the validate() method is not working.
Here is my code.
LoginController:

```
<?php
namespace backend\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use Yii;


class LoginController extends Controller{

    public $layout = 'login' ;

    public function actionIndex(){

        $model = new LoginForm();

            if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->validate())){
                return $this->redirect(['site/index']);
            }else{
            var_dump(Yii::$app->request->isPost);
            echo "<br>";
            var_dump($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()));    
            echo "To be continued...";
            }

        return $this->render('index',['model' => $model]);
    }

}
```

Here it is the LoginForm.php:

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

class LoginForm extends Model{

    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    public $verification;

    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['username','password'],'required','message'=>'{attribute}Write Something...'],
            ['username','validateUser'],
            //['password', 'validatePassword'],
            ];
    }
/*Continue later after redirect works    
    public function validateUser($attribute,$params){
        $user = User::findOne(['username'=>$this->$attribute]);
        if(!$user || (md5($this->password) != $user['password'])){
            $this->addError($this->attribute,'Errors Here...');
        }

    }
*/
```

And here is my login/index.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use Yii;

//http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html
$this->registerCssFile('@web/css/bslogin.css');

?>

<div class="container">
<?=Html::beginForm('','post',['class'=>'form-signin'])?>

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

        <?=Html::activeInput('text',$model,'username',['id'=>'username','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Username','autofocus'=>true])?>
        <?=Html::error($model,'username')?>

        <?=Html::activeInput('password', $model,'password',['id'=>'inputPassword','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password'])?>
        <?=Html::error($model,'password')?>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <?=Html::submitButton('Login',['class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'])?>
<?=Html::endForm()?>
</div>
```

**So, the issues are:**

- 1. While accessing and validating the user input, no matter what I type,
     the Error would show up, either Blank or Filled with values.
- 2. If I remove the **$model->validate()** from **Controller**, page will redirect to the index, but it is without validation.
- 3. If I comment the username validation on the rules, just check for required, error would show the same. Input or blank will display
     error message that "Write Something".

Not sure where I did wrong, any helps would appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you just have a syntax  mistake here:

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post() && $model->validate())){
```

Change it to

```
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
```